# jquery checkbox behave radio and save in cookie

Tags: jquery, cookies, jquery-cookie

i want the the checkbox behave like radio but should be able to checked or unchecked and save the state checkbox in cookie. Here is the cookie code, from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13936865/jquery-save-checkbox-state-on-click-in-cookie) or jsfiddle [here](http://jsfiddle.net/R73vy/)

```
$(".chb").each(function() {
var mycookie = $.cookie($(this).attr('name'));
if (mycookie && mycookie == "true") {
    $(this).prop('checked', mycookie);
}
});
$(".chb").change(function() {
$.cookie($(this).attr("name"), $(this).prop('checked'), {
    path: '/',
    expires: 365
});
});
```

i try added this code in .change but the cookie still save multiple state. its working fine without combine with cookie script. anyone can help?

```
$(".chb").not(this).prop('checked', false);
```

Comment: If you want checkboxes that behave like radios, why not use radio buttons ?

Comment: @adeneo because the requirement, it should look like checkbox. i know, i can simply use radio. unless there is other option to convert radio interface to look like checkbox. :(

Comment: one more thing, if use radio button, you cannot uncheck the checked radio. its like convert on paper exam to online exam.